# Stop scrolling page, scroll div

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating this landing page: http://tag4share.com/landing/#

Where is located the two galaxy s3 (one white with "Organizador" label on it and a black with "Participante" label), I want to stop scrolling the page and automatically start scrolling the content inside the mobile (an iFrame, div, anything).

Is it possible?

Basically I want to "focus" the scrolling inside a div (and make it work even if the cursor isn't hovering it). Or animate while scrolling without scrolling the body.

Example: http://www.google.com/nexus/5/

On the "Everything you need to capture the moments that matter." part.

My attempt:

```
var lastScroll;
var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function() {

    lastScroll = currentScroll;
    currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 2024 && $(window).scrollTop() < 2500)
    {
                var difference = currentScroll - lastScroll;
        $(".main").css({"margin-top":"-="+currentScroll});
    }
    });
```

I've tried to move the main div along with scrolling. It works but it looks really strange (keeps shaking).

Thanks!

Comment: Your issues sounds similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328273/lock-mousewheel-scroll-to-focus-div

Comment: Surely you don't expect people to write the code for you, have to tried anything? You can detect the scroll of the window with `$('window').on('scroll', function(){});`, you could then continually reposition the browser to the top and scroll the div calculating the amount the user has scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tidied up your code a tad, fixed indentation etc.

As for actually scrolling your div when you hit the position, use `animate` to actually mimic the `scrolling` effect, once you know you have reached the bottom, you can put another if statement within the scroll function to stop resetting the scroll position.

```
var lastScroll;
var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
var reachedBottom = false;
var phonePositionTop = $('#phoneContainerID').position().top;
var phonePositionBottom = phonePositionTop + $('#phoneContainerID').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if(scrollPosition >= phonePositionTop && scrollPosition < phonePositionBottom && reachedBottom == false){
        var difference = currentScroll - lastScroll;
        // Keep resetting scroll to the phoneContainerTop position
        $(".main").css({"margin-top": phonePositionTop});
        var scrollLimit = -100;
        if ($('#phoneContainerID').position().top < scrollLimit) {
            //Once the scroll limit is less than -100 (scrolled up 100 pixels)
            // Disable our 'pause' effect, and continue
            reachedBottom = true;
        }

    }
});
```

I haven't tested this, however I was just giving you an idea of where to go from here.

I hope I have helped a little!